# Vue JS - Using component inside the loop

Tags: vue.js

```js
var parent = Vue.extend({
  props: ['clientshiftlist'],
    template: '<td class="text-center">1</td>', 
});

Vue.component('parent', parent);

new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data() {
    return {
        clientList: 
        [
            {clientName:"John", shifts:[{shiftType:'sleepover', shiftHr: 10},{shiftType:'training', shiftHr: 5}]},
          {clientName:"Adam", shifts:[{shiftType:'sleepover', shiftHr: 10},{shiftType:'training', shiftHr: 5}]}
        ],
        selectedClient: null,
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <table class="table table-striped table-sm" id="app">
     <thead>
            <tr>
                 <th scope="col">#</th>
                 <th scope="col">Client</th>
                 <th>P</th>
            </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
          <tr v-for="(client,index) in clientList">    
             <td>{{index+1}}</td>
             <td>{{client.clientName}}</td> 
             <td>
                <parent v-bind:clientshiftlist="client.shifts"></parent>
             </td>
          </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

I would like to ask a simple question about VueJs' components, please.
I have got a loop inside the  row and wanted to create columns via component.

```
 <tr v-for="client in clientList">
     <td>{{client.clientName}}</td>
     <shift-rows v-bind:clientshiftlist="client.shifts"></shift-rows>
 </tr>
```

And my vue file is:

```
const app = {
  data() {
    return {
        clientList: [..there are a list of Clients..],
        selectedClient: null,
    }
  },
}

const myApp = Vue.createApp(app);

myApp.component('shift-rows', {
props: ['clientshiftlist'],
data() {
    return {
        
    }
},
template: `
            <td class="text-center">1</td>
            <td class="text-center">2</td>
            <td class="text-center">3</td>

        `
```

})

the Error code says
**[Vue warn]: Property "client" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.**

I am not sure why the client is not defined. It is inside the loop.

Thank you

Comment: Can you show us where you define your ClientList ?

Comment: Hi Herlock. I added the Main Vue code now, but the error says "client" is not defined, which is defined inside the loop.

Comment: @Herlock it's empty array so if it's not instanciate the loop should not have any element, then the `client` will not throw error

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your current code, can you try create a demo on jsFiddle or something, so we can help?

Comment: Just check how i am doing on my vue project,  my v-for loop is inside my component tags. But yes nothing seems to be wrong actually

Comment: @vicnoob I just tried running the code on Jsffidle, and i got no error.

Comment: try to rename variable, remove part by part to see which part make it wrong, if's it's not wrong on jsfiddle then I think your code is correct, maybe conflicting with something